# How to mark a package to prevent from being installed

Tags: debian, package-management

I've detected some packages that breaks my configuration (like `light-locker`, `evince`, etc...)

How can I prevent these packages to be able to install via `apt-get install` in my system (Debian) with the provided error reason?

Comment: No, it's not duplicate. They may or may not have the same solution, questions are different.

Comment: It is not a duplicate because the question belong to AskUbuntu, also the  duplicate flag doesn't explain how to prevent a package from being installed.

Comment: @ceremcem that doesn't mean anything without also telling us what exact configuration you tried.

Comment: I mean by "not solving my case" is that it still lets me install a "banned" package. The [same answer is below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/459165/65781) and after banning a package `apt policy light-locker` still shows a candidate. It's not exactly related with my own use case, packages are still be able to install.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Pin-Priority: -1`

for example:

```
$ cat >/etc/apt/preferences.d/libsystemd0 <<EOF
Package: libsystemd0
Pin: origin ""
Pin-Priority: -1
EOF
```

Comment: I placed a file for `evince` and `apt-get install evince` still installs it. Would you confirm that you can't install some specific package with this configuration?

Comment: @ceremcem I think pining a specific package version of (a buggy) package is the best way. For example you can use `Pin: version 3.22.1-3+deb9u1` for `evince` (note that evince isn't buggy) if the package version change the package will be installed. use `apt-cache policy pkg_name` to get the exact version.

Comment: Sometimes I may want to ban a package because of a bug according to me which is a feature from the point of view of developers. For example, light-locker was my sneaky screen locker which I didn't find a way to disable it and when I learned its name, uninstalling it solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I've detected some packages that breaks my configuration (like light-locker, evince, etc...)

The `apt-listbugs` is the correct tool to deal with a buggy package allowing you to pin the package or the dependencies. For example:

```
# apt install apt-listbugs
$ apt-listbugs list light-locker

grave bugs of light-locker (-> ) <Outstanding>
 b1 - #892290 - light-locker: at unlock, crash with: arguments to dbus_message_new_method_call() were incorrect
Summary:
 light-locker(1 bug)
```

Comment: how does that help the OP ?

Comment: @BerryTsakala Only the buggy package break the system, the OP ask for a solution to prevent the buggy package from being installed. I have quoted the first line to understand what happened.

Comment: `apt-listbugs` seems a helper tool but 1. it can not prevent a package from being automatically installed, 2. it isn't a proper error handling (if we don't use it or ignore its output, the package is able to be installed, 3. we can't always examine all the bugs for every package. But it's good to know that there is such a tool.